# python.exe no module named pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, package

After installing python 3.8 version, trying to install package using below command but getting error all the time.

command: *python -m pip install pandas*

output: *python.exe no module named pip*

Comment: I suppose you're running on Windows, but it's good to point it out in your question. Also tell us what approaches you've already tried, so others don't recommend them again. `ensurepip` is one of the potential solutions, so downvoting without communicating why is not helpful

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+python.exe+no+module+named+pip

Answer (score 3):

Try running [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html) to get the pip module installed:

```
python -m ensurepip
```

If that fails, look into installing the `python3-pip` package using your OS's package manager